# Concatenating values in a 3d array to 2d array efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3 dimensional array `A` that I want to sum the values across one of the axis and create a 2d array containing the sums.

This can naively be done by iterating across the 3d array using loops but doing it this way is very slow.

[`A = np.sum(A,axis=0)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) can achieve this much faster than the naive way, but is there something faster?

I came across this answer done in Matlab: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/3643-efficiently-converting-a-3d-matrix-to-a-2d-matrix

I was wondering if there was a similarly efficient way to do this in Python.

The following is what Im looking for:

```
A = np.ones((3, 3, 3))

# numpy magic ...

print (A)

/**********
* [3, 3, 3],
* [3, 3, 3],
* [3, 3, 3]
***********/
```

Comment: the matlab thread you attached is about just concating, you are saying you want to sum along axis, in numpy I'm pretty sure `np.sum` will be the fastest solution. If you want to duplicate the matlab code, you can use `np.transpose` and `np.reshape`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.sum()` to sum values along specified axis, this works as dimensionality reduction function

```py
a = np.ones((3, 3, 3))
np.sum(a, axis=2) # sums along "channels" axis
np.sum(a, axis=1) # sums along "columns" axis
np.sum(a, axis=0) # sums along "rows" axis
```

Comment: This adds nothing to answer the question.

Comment: it may seem so now but op edited in the section about `np.sum` after I posted the answer

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that your best bet is to use the method [`ndarray.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sum.html) rather than [`np.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html). The internal processing will be the same, but when you use the method, you do not need to check if the object being passed in is already an array and potentially convert it. That being said, the difference in overhead is very minimal.

The internal loop is already written in C and optimized as far as it's likely to go. The only additional improvement I can think of is that it is always fastest to sum along a contiguous axis. You can ensure this by using something like [`np.moveaxis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) followed by [`copy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html) to guarantee contiguity:

```
def fastsum(x, axis):
    if x.strides[axis] != x.itemsize:
        x = np.moveaxis(x, axis, -1).copy(order="C")
        axis = -1
    return x.sum(axis)
```

This function is not really efficient. For small arrays, any gains are likely to be overwhelmed by the overhead of python and numpy object protocols. Your best bet is to ensure that the array is generated in the correct order to begin with and just use `x.sum(-1)` on C-contiguous arrays or `x.sum(0)` on Fortran-contiguous ones.